# Command inside if statement in batch script to append to file and create a new file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script file that creates a log for me, it runs every 10 minutes
and what i want it to do is every 50 minutes append the contents of the file to another file and clean the original file.

my problem is that the command inside my if statement does nothing, even when i put the simplest commands like echo working or something.
my code looks like this

```
SET check=%time:~3,2%
SET /a res=%check%%%50
IF %res%==0 (
   type logFile.txt >> AllLogs.txt
   echo.> logFile1.txt
```

)

Comment: Try using a numeric comparison, rather than a string.  `IF %res% EQU 0`

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- in **logic**: `%res%==0` results to `true` if and only if current minute is either `0` or `50` (probability to hit the right time is about `2:60`, e.g. `3.33 %`);
- in **scripting**: `SET /a res=%check%%%50` [could fail if current minute is either `8` or `9`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) in so far that `%check%` results to `08` or `09`. Use `SET /a res=100%check%%%50` (in fact, `10%check%%%50` should suffice).

> The octal notation can be confusing - all numeric values that start
>   with zeros are treated as octal but `08` and `09` are not valid octal
>   digits.

Then (hard coded `check` as can't wait):

```
==>SET check
check=09

==>SET /a res=%check%%50
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).

==>SET res
Environment variable res not defined

==>SET /a res=100%check%%50
9
==>
```

Comment: you are right on both accounts the %% operator was running on a 0 minute as well i decided to run it every hour and put my equation to be like this 

SET check=%time:~3,2%

IF %check%==50 GOTO :1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using a GOTO :1

and putting the commands i wanted under :1
 it fixed my problem

```
SET check=%time:~3,2%

IF %check%==50 GOTO :1

:1
@type 
@echo
```